# Gmaps4rails Gem show 2 markers for same address

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to implement `gmaps4rails gem` and `geocoder gem`, which works fine. The only thing at the `index.html.erb` page, where I list my boats and show map that I can not show more than 1 marker if I have more than 1 same address. I would like to show something like;

[image]

Here is my `locations_controller`;

```
def index

    if params[:search].present? 
        @locations = Location.near(params[:search], 5) #Kac mile cevresinde aranıldıgının bilgisi bu km ile değişebilir
    else
        @locations = Location.all
    end
    @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@locations) do |location, marker|
        marker.lat location.latitude
        marker.lng location.longitude
        marker.infowindow render_to_string(:partial => "/locations/my_template", :locals => { :object => location}) 
    end
  end
```

This is my `index.html.erb`;

```
<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.13&amp;sensor=false&amp;libraries=geometry" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='//google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.14/src/markerclusterer_packed.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

<h3>Nearby locations</h3>
<ul>
<% @locations.each do |location| %>
  <li><%=location.address %></li> (<%= location.distance.round(2) %> miles)

<% end %>
</ul>




<div style='width: 800px;'>
  <div id="map" style='width: 800px; height: 400px;'></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
  markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
  handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
  handler.fitMapToBounds();
});
</script>
```

It only shows 1 marker even though I have more than 1 address for the same latitude and longitude. How can I overcome with it?

**EDIT 1:**

Here what it looks like;

[image]

Then zoom out;

[image]

And this is what I added as you said;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
handler = Gmaps.build('Google', { markers: { maxRandomDistance: 5 } });
handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
  markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
  handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
  handler.fitMapToBounds();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its the problem with any map: you cant have two things at the same place.

Since its a common issue, there is an option in the gem though:

```
handler = Gmaps.build('Google', { markers: { maxRandomDistance: integerInMeters } });
```

this will slightly randomize the coordinates you give within a `maxRandomDistance` distance of the expected center

Comment: Thank you, I have read about `randomize` in gmaps4rails wiki. I think it is the same thing right?. But when I pass the argument and zoom out the map. Now It does not sum / combine the markers as the picture I posted. Should I add other parameters?. It should be auto, right?

Comment: I dont understand what you did but it should be auto if you do what I wrote

Comment: I think I should edit the zoom out property. When I totally zoom out the map then it shows the sum of them.